# To remove date picker value in properties using windows form

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I have a date picker in which i have set a value in property window in windows form.When i try to remove the value it shows a alert msg "property value is not valid".Pls anyone help me to remove the date picker value in property
.

Comment: You are looking for something called a [Nullable DateTimePicker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5428/Nullable-DateTimePicker)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.DateTimePicker.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
this.DateTimePicker.CustomFormat = " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide the value in the `DateTimePicker`, you can set a custom format:

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
```

Comment: The selected date value still exist.Issue is not solved

Comment: how can i hide the value from the user